# twig undefined php variable

Tags: php, twig

Hi I've just started to study twig and I've got the following error:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: message

This is the way i render the view from my controller:

```
echo $twig->render('/km-profile/km-edit-password.twig', array('error' => $message) );
```

The variable $message comes from the model and it is an array that looks like

```
$message = array(
            'message' => 'please fill in all fields!',
            'status' => 'error'
        );
```

In the view I'm using twig in the following way:

```
{% if error is defined and error.status == 'error' %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error.message|raw}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

The `$message` variable is only set after I submit the form and detect an error. I know i could put an empty `$message` array before I start validation in the model, then it will solve the php error message, but I don't understand why I still get it even if I put "is defined" into twig logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I don't understand why i still get it even if i put "is defined" into twig logic

Because the error is not generated from twig but here:

```
echo $twig->render('/km-profile/km-edit-password.twig', array('error' => $message) );
```

try

```
$params = [];
if(!empty($message)) { 
    $params['error'] = $message;
}
echo $twig->render('/km-profile/km-edit-password.twig', $params);
```

If you have `PHP > 7` you can make use of the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) too:

```
echo $twig->render('/km-profile/km-edit-password.twig', ['error' => $message ?? false]);
```

or with `PHP < 7`:

```
echo $twig->render('/km-profile/km-edit-password.twig', ['error' => isset($message) ? $message : false]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, yes it works, so is it always better to build a new array and then pass it to render? many thanks

Comment: @pippo You could aswell do `array('error' => $message ?? false)` see updated answer. Its all just about not using undefined variables and those are ways to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

@Xatenev answer is correct, but I prefer not to make mess in controller code, IMHO it's better to check variable existence in template.

Try this:

```
{% if error is defined and error.status == 'error' and error.message is defined  %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error.message|raw}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if error is defined and error.status == 'error'  %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {%if error.message is defined %}
               {{error.message|raw}}
          {% endif %}
      </div>
{% endif %}
```